# Android Volley does not load data from server when recreating an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have three Activities, namely A, B and C.

Activities A and C are FragmentActivities

Finishing from Activity B is fine, since Volley will work properly in Activity A.

Same thing when finishing Activity C.

However, when I want to go from Activity C to A, I have to destroy B. It worked, but the problem is, I received no data from Volley when loading to Activity A.

Comment: without code, we are not magician to know your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add these flags when starting activity A

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and add flag in manifest also

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

you will be getting new callback onNewIntent(Intent intent) if you want to send any data